# sf for point-to-polygon producing unexpected results

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I am trying to run (what I believe should be) a simple point-to-polygon count (and sum of a point attribute, but if we can figure out the former, I think I can figure out the latter) using the `sf` package. I have used `st_transform` to ensure that both my point and polygon `sf` objects are projected in the same CRS.

I have followed instructions here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323698/counting-points-in-polygons-with-sf-package-of-r and here https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/spatial-operations.html#spatial-aggr. Neither method has worked. For the subset I am trying to use as an example, I get all 0 for the counts when I know for sure (having mapped the data in QGIS) that the points here occupy some of these polygons. Code is below.

The data here are a small subset of data I have for 50+ cities. This is from a single county for both the points and the polygons. I anticipate being yelled at about the code not being reproducible because of the truncation of the geometry variable; I am having difficulty copying an `sf` object over to StackOverflow as the geometry column keeps getting truncated (despite my efforts to lift the character limit in the RStudio console). If someone can guide me on how to print the entirety of my two sf objects I will gladly drop them into the code section to make the reprex useable. Below my bit of script I've pasted what I'm able to print using `print.data.frame`. I haven't been able to find any guidance on getting copyable `sf` data on Stack, but perhaps I've missed something.

Thank you any and all who can provide guidance.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(reprex)
library(sf)

polydata <- st_transform(polydata, crs=4326)

pointdata <- st_transform(pointdata, crs=4326)

# Attempt one based on https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323698/counting-points-in-polygons-with-sf-package-of-r
polydata$foos <- (lengths(st_intersects(polydata, pointdata)))
although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersects assumes that they are planar

unique(polydata$foos)
[1] 0

# Attempt two based on https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/spatial-operations.html#spatial-aggr
footable <- st_join(pointdata, polydata, join = st_intersects)
foocounts <- count(as_tibble(footable), GEOID) %>%
  print()

> print.data.frame(polydata)
    state        county        GEOID                       geometry
1      TX Travis County 484530022081 MULTIPOLYGON (((-158678.5 -...
2      TX Travis County 484530024331 MULTIPOLYGON (((-150935.3 -...
3      TX Travis County 484530002041 MULTIPOLYGON (((-166903.4 -...
4      TX Travis County 484530017402 MULTIPOLYGON (((-177882 -81...
5      TX Travis County 484530018554 MULTIPOLYGON (((-155772.7 -...
6      TX Travis County 484530018584 MULTIPOLYGON (((-151218.4 -...
7      TX Travis County 484530018585 MULTIPOLYGON (((-150767.6 -...
8      TX Travis County 484530018592 MULTIPOLYGON (((-147824.6 -...
9      TX Travis County 484530018622 MULTIPOLYGON (((-154959.5 -...
10     TX Travis County 484530019082 MULTIPOLYGON (((-179504.2 -...
11     TX Travis County 484530022093 MULTIPOLYGON (((-135256.4 -...
12     TX Travis County 484530022102 MULTIPOLYGON (((-139312.3 -...
13     TX Travis County 484530015032 MULTIPOLYGON (((-164329.6 -...
14     TX Travis County 484530015033 MULTIPOLYGON (((-164685.6 -...
15     TX Travis County 484530015013 MULTIPOLYGON (((-166918.9 -...
16     TX Travis County 484530015034 MULTIPOLYGON (((-163591.3 -...
17     TX Travis County 484530023144 MULTIPOLYGON (((-165340.5 -...
18     TX Travis County 484530019011 MULTIPOLYGON (((-169939.2 -...
19     TX Travis County 484530010005 MULTIPOLYGON (((-166245 -80...
20     TX Travis County 484530021113 MULTIPOLYGON (((-161241.1 -...
21     TX Travis County 484530020031 MULTIPOLYGON (((-170088.5 -...
22     TX Travis County 484530020041 MULTIPOLYGON (((-171620.7 -...
23     TX Travis County 484530023043 MULTIPOLYGON (((-165246.4 -...
24     TX Travis County 484530018331 MULTIPOLYGON (((-160729.8 -...
25     TX Travis County 484530018233 MULTIPOLYGON (((-161256.9 -...
26     TX Travis County 484530024271 MULTIPOLYGON (((-168314.5 -...
27     TX Travis County 484530017372 MULTIPOLYGON (((-180321.1 -...
28     TX Travis County 484530019193 MULTIPOLYGON (((-172758.9 -...
29     TX Travis County 484530023141 MULTIPOLYGON (((-165406.8 -...
30     TX Travis County 484530024302 MULTIPOLYGON (((-169134.4 -...
31     TX Travis County 484530018601 MULTIPOLYGON (((-156799.8 -...
32     TX Travis County 484530024301 MULTIPOLYGON (((-167825.6 -...
33     TX Travis County 484530024092 MULTIPOLYGON (((-172376.3 -...
34     TX Travis County 484530002063 MULTIPOLYGON (((-166999 -79...
35     TX Travis County 484530018221 MULTIPOLYGON (((-162436.2 -...
36     TX Travis County 484530018231 MULTIPOLYGON (((-161486.7 -...
37     TX Travis County 484530017521 MULTIPOLYGON (((-167544.9 -...
38     TX Travis County 484530018201 MULTIPOLYGON (((-164095 -79...
39     TX Travis County 484530018202 MULTIPOLYGON (((-164599.6 -...
40     TX Travis County 484530018224 MULTIPOLYGON (((-163040.2 -...
41     TX Travis County 484530017162 MULTIPOLYGON (((-170599 -79...
42     TX Travis County 484530017193 MULTIPOLYGON (((-171546.6 -...
43     TX Travis County 484530015014 MULTIPOLYGON (((-166583.9 -...
44     TX Travis County 484530015031 MULTIPOLYGON (((-164409.9 -...
45     TX Travis County 484530003042 MULTIPOLYGON (((-164620.7 -...
46     TX Travis County 484530002031 MULTIPOLYGON (((-166198.6 -...
47     TX Travis County 484530003051 MULTIPOLYGON (((-164992.3 -...
48     TX Travis County 484530003025 MULTIPOLYGON (((-165600.3 -...
49     TX Travis County 484530003071 MULTIPOLYGON (((-163964.2 -...
50     TX Travis County 484530013071 MULTIPOLYGON (((-169723.4 -...
51     TX Travis County 484530015052 MULTIPOLYGON (((-165703.9 -...
52     TX Travis County 484530018123 MULTIPOLYGON (((-163126.4 -...
53     TX Travis County 484530018172 MULTIPOLYGON (((-166326 -79...
54     TX Travis County 484530017531 MULTIPOLYGON (((-165898.5 -...
55     TX Travis County 484530018322 MULTIPOLYGON (((-159700.8 -...
56     TX Travis County 484530018353 MULTIPOLYGON (((-159137.9 -...
57     TX Travis County 484530018392 MULTIPOLYGON (((-158355.8 -...
58     TX Travis County 484530017131 MULTIPOLYGON (((-173491.6 -...
59     TX Travis County 484530017133 MULTIPOLYGON (((-172801.8 -...
60     TX Travis County 484530017422 MULTIPOLYGON (((-183655 -79...
61     TX Travis County 484530017821 MULTIPOLYGON (((-170367.5 -...
62     TX Travis County 484530017571 MULTIPOLYGON (((-169180.4 -...
63     TX Travis County 484530022023 MULTIPOLYGON (((-155641.4 -...
64     TX Travis County 484530023143 MULTIPOLYGON (((-165485.9 -...
65     TX Travis County 484530017852 MULTIPOLYGON (((-166701.8 -...
66     TX Travis County 484530004012 MULTIPOLYGON (((-165490.6 -...
67     TX Travis County 484530003061 MULTIPOLYGON (((-164164.7 -...
68     TX Travis County 484530007001 MULTIPOLYGON (((-167919.3 -...
69     TX Travis County 484530013032 MULTIPOLYGON (((-168807.1 -...
70     TX Travis County 484530017561 MULTIPOLYGON (((-169064.3 -...
71     TX Travis County 484530017864 MULTIPOLYGON (((-166430.5 -...
72     TX Travis County 484530017552 MULTIPOLYGON (((-169566.4 -...
73     TX Travis County 484530017721 MULTIPOLYGON (((-176068.2 -...
74     TX Travis County 484530017751 MULTIPOLYGON (((-182973.3 -...
75     TX Travis County 484530017551 MULTIPOLYGON (((-169181.5 -...
76     TX Travis County 484530019182 MULTIPOLYGON (((-174913.5 -...
77     TX Travis County 484530017742 MULTIPOLYGON (((-176325.9 -...
78     TX Travis County 484530017743 MULTIPOLYGON (((-177969.1 -...
79     TX Travis County 484530017701 MULTIPOLYGON (((-182994 -81...
80     TX Travis County 484530017703 MULTIPOLYGON (((-182197.4 -...
81     TX Travis County 484530017761 MULTIPOLYGON (((-175946.2 -...
82     TX Travis County 484530017762 MULTIPOLYGON (((-177520.1 -...
83     TX Travis County 484530017741 MULTIPOLYGON (((-177950.5 -...
84     TX Travis County 484530017411 MULTIPOLYGON (((-183240.8 -...
85     TX Travis County 484530017421 MULTIPOLYGON (((-183164 -79...
86     TX Travis County 484530017781 MULTIPOLYGON (((-186798.4 -...
87     TX Travis County 484530017782 MULTIPOLYGON (((-187511.2 -...
88     TX Travis County 484530017731 MULTIPOLYGON (((-189056.5 -...
89     TX Travis County 484530024213 MULTIPOLYGON (((-171699.2 -...
90     TX Travis County 484530018641 MULTIPOLYGON (((-162407.2 -...
91     TX Travis County 484530018642 MULTIPOLYGON (((-161578.4 -...
92     TX Travis County 484530018511 MULTIPOLYGON (((-160760.6 -...
93     TX Travis County 484530018461 MULTIPOLYGON (((-162758.8 -...
94     TX Travis County 484530024231 MULTIPOLYGON (((-173686.1 -...
95     TX Travis County 484530017493 MULTIPOLYGON (((-175369.3 -...
96     TX Travis County 484530017494 MULTIPOLYGON (((-176808.2 -...
97     TX Travis County 484530019151 MULTIPOLYGON (((-176543.6 -...
98     TX Travis County 484530017071 MULTIPOLYGON (((-166905.9 -...
99     TX Travis County 484530018051 MULTIPOLYGON (((-164408.2 -...
100    TX Travis County 484530018063 MULTIPOLYGON (((-162533.6 -...
101    TX Travis County 484530018064 MULTIPOLYGON (((-163016.5 -...
102    TX Travis County 484530018111 MULTIPOLYGON (((-161688.5 -...
103    TX Travis County 484530018342 MULTIPOLYGON (((-157897.4 -...
104    TX Travis County 484530018352 MULTIPOLYGON (((-158880.4 -...
105    TX Travis County 484530018321 MULTIPOLYGON (((-159633.4 -...
106    TX Travis County 484530018421 MULTIPOLYGON (((-153073.2 -...
107    TX Travis County 484530018612 MULTIPOLYGON (((-156653.2 -...
108    TX Travis County 484530018602 MULTIPOLYGON (((-157997.7 -...
109    TX Travis County 484530018513 MULTIPOLYGON (((-160163.8 -...
110    TX Travis County 484530018514 MULTIPOLYGON (((-160392.3 -...
111    TX Travis County 484530018553 MULTIPOLYGON (((-152648.8 -...
112    TX Travis County 484530018582 MULTIPOLYGON (((-150907.9 -...
113    TX Travis County 484530018581 MULTIPOLYGON (((-148468.1 -...
114    TX Travis County 484530005002 MULTIPOLYGON (((-166108.1 -...
115    TX Travis County 484530021122 MULTIPOLYGON (((-161203.5 -...
116    TX Travis County 484530017863 MULTIPOLYGON (((-167259 -78...
117    TX Travis County 484530017663 MULTIPOLYGON (((-183712.5 -...
118    TX Travis County 484530019111 MULTIPOLYGON (((-169137.1 -...
119    TX Travis County 484530019104 MULTIPOLYGON (((-172058 -80...
120    TX Travis County 484530023142 MULTIPOLYGON (((-164153.8 -...
121    TX Travis County 484530024282 MULTIPOLYGON (((-170189.4 -...
122    TX Travis County 484530018402 MULTIPOLYGON (((-156823.2 -...
123    TX Travis County 484530018591 MULTIPOLYGON (((-143870 -78...
124    TX Travis County 484530018414 MULTIPOLYGON (((-155303.8 -...
125    TX Travis County 484530022121 MULTIPOLYGON (((-152172.9 -...
126    TX Travis County 484530016021 MULTIPOLYGON (((-170693.2 -...
127    TX Travis County 484530016023 MULTIPOLYGON (((-171498.5 -...
128    TX Travis County 484530019191 MULTIPOLYGON (((-171622.4 -...
129    TX Travis County 484530017223 MULTIPOLYGON (((-167985.8 -...
130    TX Travis County 484530024072 MULTIPOLYGON (((-172912.8 -...
131    TX Travis County 484530017412 MULTIPOLYGON (((-184069.2 -...
132    TX Travis County 484530017283 MULTIPOLYGON (((-174679.4 -...
133    TX Travis County 484530019183 MULTIPOLYGON (((-172714.4 -...
134    TX Travis County 484530002053 MULTIPOLYGON (((-166640 -79...
135    TX Travis County 484530001022 MULTIPOLYGON (((-168592.5 -...
136    TX Travis County 484530016031 MULTIPOLYGON (((-167921.3 -...
137    TX Travis County 484530018632 MULTIPOLYGON (((-160275.8 -...
138    TX Travis County 484530018631 MULTIPOLYGON (((-160788.4 -...
139    TX Travis County 484530018422 MULTIPOLYGON (((-152222.3 -...
140    TX Travis County 484530022082 MULTIPOLYGON (((-158096.8 -...
141    TX Travis County 484530017711 MULTIPOLYGON (((-188447 -79...
142    TX Travis County 484530019173 MULTIPOLYGON (((-176300.3 -...
143    TX Travis County 484530017523 MULTIPOLYGON (((-167685.5 -...
144    TX Travis County 484530017062 MULTIPOLYGON (((-168810.4 -...
145    TX Travis County 484530017061 MULTIPOLYGON (((-168205.6 -...
146    TX Travis County 484530017054 MULTIPOLYGON (((-168593.9 -...
147    TX Travis County 484530006031 MULTIPOLYGON (((-167837.8 -...
148    TX Travis County 484530018491 MULTIPOLYGON (((-164013.7 -...
149    TX Travis County 484530019142 MULTIPOLYGON (((-175633.3 -...
150    TX Travis County 484530019143 MULTIPOLYGON (((-173996.9 -...
151    TX Travis County 484530019171 MULTIPOLYGON (((-175566.7 -...
152    TX Travis County 484530024112 MULTIPOLYGON (((-168395 -81...
153    TX Travis County 484530020032 MULTIPOLYGON (((-169567.5 -...
154    TX Travis County 484530022022 MULTIPOLYGON (((-155838.7 -...
155    TX Travis County 484530018493 MULTIPOLYGON (((-162818.6 -...
156    TX Travis County 484530018494 MULTIPOLYGON (((-163332.1 -...
157    TX Travis County 484530017063 MULTIPOLYGON (((-166761.1 -...
158    TX Travis County 484530017073 MULTIPOLYGON (((-166761.1 -...
159    TX Travis County 484530018492 MULTIPOLYGON (((-165134.6 -...
160    TX Travis County 484530017542 MULTIPOLYGON (((-165822.1 -...
161    TX Travis County 484530018112 MULTIPOLYGON (((-160625.4 -...
162    TX Travis County 484530021133 MULTIPOLYGON (((-160010.3 -...
163    TX Travis County 484530021131 MULTIPOLYGON (((-159683.9 -...
164    TX Travis County 484530022084 MULTIPOLYGON (((-157424.1 -...
165    TX Travis County 484530022021 MULTIPOLYGON (((-155641.4 -...
166    TX Travis County 484530022111 MULTIPOLYGON (((-153685.3 -...
167    TX Travis County 484530024361 MULTIPOLYGON (((-158859.4 -...
168    TX Travis County 484530023171 MULTIPOLYGON (((-163353.4 -...
169    TX Travis County 484530017281 MULTIPOLYGON (((-173999.9 -...
170    TX Travis County 484530017282 MULTIPOLYGON (((-173716.2 -...
171    TX Travis County 484530016032 MULTIPOLYGON (((-168184.8 -...
172    TX Travis County 484530016033 MULTIPOLYGON (((-168640.4 -...
173    TX Travis County 484530016034 MULTIPOLYGON (((-167811.7 -...
174    TX Travis County 484530017371 MULTIPOLYGON (((-179211.2 -...
175    TX Travis County 484530017284 MULTIPOLYGON (((-173240.7 -...
176    TX Travis County 484530017222 MULTIPOLYGON (((-167437.6 -...
177    TX Travis County 484530017373 MULTIPOLYGON (((-179603.5 -...
178    TX Travis County 484530016043 MULTIPOLYGON (((-169463.2 -...
179    TX Travis County 484530016044 MULTIPOLYGON (((-169807.1 -...
180    TX Travis County 484530016051 MULTIPOLYGON (((-169025.4 -...
181    TX Travis County 484530016052 MULTIPOLYGON (((-168669.7 -...
182    TX Travis County 484530016053 MULTIPOLYGON (((-168388.5 -...
183    TX Travis County 484530016054 MULTIPOLYGON (((-168832.9 -...
184    TX Travis County 484530017053 MULTIPOLYGON (((-169740.5 -...
185    TX Travis County 484530017072 MULTIPOLYGON (((-167030.9 -...
186    TX Travis County 484530017121 MULTIPOLYGON (((-172203.2 -...
187    TX Travis County 484530017122 MULTIPOLYGON (((-172444.4 -...
188    TX Travis County 484530017132 MULTIPOLYGON (((-172421.8 -...
189    TX Travis County 484530017811 MULTIPOLYGON (((-172014.2 -...
190    TX Travis County 484530017823 MULTIPOLYGON (((-171977.8 -...
191    TX Travis County 484530017181 MULTIPOLYGON (((-167748.7 -...
192    TX Travis County 484530017182 MULTIPOLYGON (((-168647.2 -...
193    TX Travis County 484530017183 MULTIPOLYGON (((-168572.3 -...
194    TX Travis County 484530017184 MULTIPOLYGON (((-169256.1 -...
195    TX Travis County 484530017191 MULTIPOLYGON (((-171457.1 -...
196    TX Travis County 484530017192 MULTIPOLYGON (((-170066.3 -...
197    TX Travis County 484530017221 MULTIPOLYGON (((-168219.4 -...
198    TX Travis County 484530017771 MULTIPOLYGON (((-177647.4 -...
199    TX Travis County 484530017401 MULTIPOLYGON (((-177201 -81...
200    TX Travis County 484530018542 MULTIPOLYGON (((-144010.1 -...
201    TX Travis County 484530017451 MULTIPOLYGON (((-165751.3 -...
202    TX Travis County 484530017461 MULTIPOLYGON (((-176290.2 -...
203    TX Travis County 484530017383 MULTIPOLYGON (((-179024.6 -...
204    TX Travis County 484530017384 MULTIPOLYGON (((-178570.5 -...
205    TX Travis County 484530017285 MULTIPOLYGON (((-175195.8 -...
206    TX Travis County 484530017291 MULTIPOLYGON (((-175779.2 -...
207    TX Travis County 484530017752 MULTIPOLYGON (((-179045.9 -...
208    TX Travis County 484530017331 MULTIPOLYGON (((-183558.9 -...
209    TX Travis County 484530017332 MULTIPOLYGON (((-182777.4 -...
210    TX Travis County 484530017385 MULTIPOLYGON (((-177386.6 -...
211    TX Travis County 484530017772 MULTIPOLYGON (((-176945.1 -...
212    TX Travis County 484530017832 MULTIPOLYGON (((-177895.4 -...
213    TX Travis County 484530016041 MULTIPOLYGON (((-169666.3 -...
214    TX Travis County 484530016042 MULTIPOLYGON (((-169242.4 -...
215    TX Travis County 484530017572 MULTIPOLYGON (((-169094.4 -...
216    TX Travis County 484530017543 MULTIPOLYGON (((-167342.8 -...
217    TX Travis County 484530017501 MULTIPOLYGON (((-174750.1 -...
218    TX Travis County 484530017541 MULTIPOLYGON (((-166554.8 -...
219    TX Travis County 484530017503 MULTIPOLYGON (((-173620.5 -...
220    TX Travis County 484530017512 MULTIPOLYGON (((-167855.6 -...
221    TX Travis County 484530017522 MULTIPOLYGON (((-167290.3 -...
222    TX Travis County 484530017462 MULTIPOLYGON (((-175515.8 -...
223    TX Travis County 484530017473 MULTIPOLYGON (((-174655.5 -...
224    TX Travis County 484530017482 MULTIPOLYGON (((-176496.7 -...
225    TX Travis County 484530017491 MULTIPOLYGON (((-177378.2 -...
226    TX Travis County 484530017492 MULTIPOLYGON (((-177378.2 -...
227    TX Travis County 484530018572 MULTIPOLYGON (((-157476.8 -...
228    TX Travis County 484530024252 MULTIPOLYGON (((-170785.6 -...
229    TX Travis County 484530017812 MULTIPOLYGON (((-170635.8 -...
230    TX Travis County 484530017842 MULTIPOLYGON (((-181830.9 -...
231    TX Travis County 484530017732 MULTIPOLYGON (((-191759.8 -...
232    TX Travis County 484530017733 MULTIPOLYGON (((-189889 -79...
233    TX Travis County 484530022092 MULTIPOLYGON (((-144463.2 -...
234    TX Travis County 484530017802 MULTIPOLYGON (((-180548.6 -...
235    TX Travis County 484530017792 MULTIPOLYGON (((-190812.2 -...
236    TX Travis County 484530017791 MULTIPOLYGON (((-189189.6 -...
237    TX Travis County 484530017793 MULTIPOLYGON (((-189744 -78...
238    TX Travis County 484530017691 MULTIPOLYGON (((-179964.4 -...
239    TX Travis County 484530017692 MULTIPOLYGON (((-181470.2 -...
240    TX Travis County 484530018043 MULTIPOLYGON (((-163457.9 -...
241    TX Travis County 484530018052 MULTIPOLYGON (((-164058.2 -...
242    TX Travis County 484530018061 MULTIPOLYGON (((-161989.6 -...
243    TX Travis County 484530018062 MULTIPOLYGON (((-162090 -79...
244    TX Travis County 484530024262 MULTIPOLYGON (((-167517.4 -...
245    TX Travis County 484530024212 MULTIPOLYGON (((-173308.4 -...
246    TX Travis County 484530008021 MULTIPOLYGON (((-163323.8 -...
247    TX Travis County 484530012003 MULTIPOLYGON (((-169312.5 -...
248    TX Travis County 484530014031 MULTIPOLYGON (((-166534.9 -...
249    TX Travis County 484530018191 MULTIPOLYGON (((-162830.9 -...
250    TX Travis County 484530021074 MULTIPOLYGON (((-160672.3 -...
 [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 330 rows ]

> print.data.frame(pointdata)
     CITY STATE county_fips county_name latitude longitude n_units                   geometry
1  AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.24713 -97.77521      NA POINT (-97.77521 30.24713)
2  AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.24786 -97.88966      NA POINT (-97.88966 30.24786)
3  AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.21521 -97.70253      NA POINT (-97.70253 30.21521)
4  AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.21531 -97.70224      NA POINT (-97.70224 30.21531)
5  AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.31370 -97.68330     240   POINT (-97.6833 30.3137)
6  AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.38120 -97.70750     240   POINT (-97.7075 30.3812)
7  AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.40067 -97.84644     120 POINT (-97.84644 30.40067)
8  AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.38775 -97.64782     216 POINT (-97.64782 30.38775)
9  AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.16940 -97.83580      95   POINT (-97.8358 30.1694)
10 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.26350 -97.74230       0   POINT (-97.7423 30.2635)
11 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.29899 -97.67405     292 POINT (-97.67405 30.29899)
12 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.31450 -97.62920     324   POINT (-97.6292 30.3145)
13 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.19022 -97.77806     194 POINT (-97.77806 30.19022)
14 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.36853 -97.70362     200 POINT (-97.70362 30.36853)
15 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.27339 -97.70004      50 POINT (-97.70004 30.27339)
16 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.35078 -97.70326      94 POINT (-97.70326 30.35078)
17 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.23723 -97.78383      33 POINT (-97.78383 30.23723)
18 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.32564 -97.74223     130 POINT (-97.74223 30.32564)
19 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.37082 -97.71654      50 POINT (-97.71654 30.37082)
20 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.19890 -97.78093      50  POINT (-97.78093 30.1989)
21 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.42094 -97.75473      75 POINT (-97.75473 30.42094)
22 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.26156 -97.69203     182 POINT (-97.69203 30.26156)
23 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.36293 -97.68294     172 POINT (-97.68294 30.36293)
24 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.19179 -97.83313     140 POINT (-97.83313 30.19179)
25 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.23640 -97.76830      70   POINT (-97.7683 30.2364)
26 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.35640 -97.65950     280   POINT (-97.6595 30.3564)
27 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.34850 -97.67646     263  POINT (-97.67646 30.3485)
28 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.40611 -97.64242     324 POINT (-97.64242 30.40611)
29 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.12980 -97.77820     304   POINT (-97.7782 30.1298)
30 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.31450 -97.62920     264   POINT (-97.6292 30.3145)
31 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.24872 -97.58654     302 POINT (-97.58654 30.24872)
32 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.38909 -97.65118      80 POINT (-97.65118 30.38909)
33 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.30760 -97.69100     132    POINT (-97.691 30.3076)
34 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.17081 -97.72212     312 POINT (-97.72212 30.17081)
35 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.15644 -97.75386     174 POINT (-97.75386 30.15644)
36 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.31276 -97.68960     100  POINT (-97.6896 30.31276)
37 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.24837 -97.77380     120  POINT (-97.7738 30.24837)
38 AUSTIN    TX       48453      Travis 30.27257 -97.74112       2 POINT (-97.74112 30.27257)
```

Comment: st_crs only reads or in your case sets the projection it doesn't transform the geometry. You need st_transform to transform them. i.e. st_transform(polydata, crs=4326) and st_transform(pointdata, crs=4326).

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, at80. However, I still get all 0 values when running the joins.

Comment: Check your polydata geometry. The geometry data do not appear to be latitude/longitude. They are likely a different projection than 4326. If that's the case then the data wouldn't return anything because they do not overlap.

Comment: I think you're correct. I re-saved the polygon source file from QGIS as a new shapefile in the appropriate CRS and it now seems to work in R. I guess the new question is how to appropriately do this conversion in R.